# DynamoDB - Modeling bidirectional many-to-many relationship?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I'm having a hard time modeling a certain scenario without having to appeal to more than one request.

Think about a `People` table, each `Person` can be related to eachother n times, and this relationship has a description.

Consider the following modelling :

[image]

As you can see, I have two `People`, and `person_0001` is child of `person_0002`.

Now, in this case, if I want to get all relationships that `person_0001` has, it's easy, I just query :

```
GET WHERE PK = "person_0001" AND SK.BEGINS_WITH("rel")
```

But, since it is bidirectional, how can I get the relationships `person_0002` has?

I could use a GSI that inverts the keys, so with one request I can simply query both tables at once.

But real problem comes when I need to update/delete, **How can I delete/update all relationships `person_0002` has with only one request?** I can only read from GSIs.

It's a big difficulty I have in general, what do I do when I need to do a delete/update/write on a GSI?

Comment: I'd like to hear how you solved the design issue eventually. If you found a solution, could you post it as an answer?